# Lib xml delegate selector is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, libxml2

I got one problem in Lib xml parser.

In end document the below code is here

```
-(void)endDocument 
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Failed with 404 or 500"
                                                                 forKey:@"error_message"];
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"ParsingDomain"
                                                 code:500
                                             userInfo:userInfo];

            SEL selector = @selector(parse:encounteredError: forId: forObj:);
            NSMethodSignature *sig = [(id)self.delegate methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
            if(nil != sig && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) // this codition is failed
            {
                printf("\n In the selector invocation");
                NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
                [invocation retainArguments];
                [invocation setTarget:self.delegate];
                [invocation setSelector:selector];
                [invocation setArgument:&self atIndex:2];
                [invocation setArgument:&error atIndex:3];
                [invocation setArgument:&Id atIndex:4];
                [invocation setArgument:&obj atIndex:5];
                [invocation performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(invoke) withObject:NULL waitUntilDone:NO];
            }
    }
```

I commented at the failed condition in above code.

Thank you,
Madan mohan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a spelling mistake check at this line

SEL selector = @selector(parse:encounteredError: forId: forObj:);

use parser instead of parse

!!!CHEERS!!!